# How to close full screen browser windows in mission control?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, mission-control

Let's say I'm browsing the web in chrome, or safari for that same matter.

I then make the window full screen by pressing control-command-F.

at that point, say I press command-N a few times to create a few more full screen windows.

Now I'll go into mission control (3 finger swipe up) and see my full screen browser windows at the top aligned just like virtual desktops.

Now for my question: how can I close these windows? There doesn't appear to be an X next to them the way virtual desktops have X's next to them?

Comment: This isn't possible.

Comment: Try [this soultion with BTT](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/closing-windows-in-mission-control.1183853/#post-14298833). It works, but not perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

Outside of Mission Control, Command-W will close a Safari window. I don't know of a way to close a window while in Mission Control.